# Select distinct from a list based on set of parameters

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a distinct list of results, distinct based on user, where the selected result would be based on a set of parameters. To break it down, I have users, logs, and files. Each user can be on multiple logs and can have multiple files. Files CAN be associated with logs or not, and can also have a 'billing' flag set to true. What I'm trying to do when someone selects a log is bring up the list of files most closely associated with both the 'billing' flag and the log.

- If the user has a file that is associated with the log AND has the
  'billing' flag set to true, that is the result for that user.
- If that is not available, the next would be the file that only has the 'billing' flag set to true (associated with any highest log or none).
- If that is not available, the highest log number.

Here is the generalization of the tables:

Test Table:

```
+----+------+-----+
| ID | user | log |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 |    1 |   2 |
|  2 |    1 |   2 |
|  3 |    2 |   2 |
|  4 |    3 |   2 |
|  5 |    3 |   2 |
|  6 |    4 |   2 |
+----+------+-----+
```

File Table:

```
+----+-------+-----+---------+------+
| ID | file  | log | billing | user |
+----+-------+-----+---------+------+
|  1 | a.pdf |   2 |       0 |    1 |
|  2 | b.pdf |   3 |       1 |    1 |
|  3 | c.pdf |   1 |       0 |    2 |
|  4 | d.pdf |   2 |       1 |    2 |
|  5 | e.pdf |   1 |       0 |    3 |
|  6 | f.pdf |   3 |       0 |    3 |
|  7 | g.pdf |   0 |       1 |    4 |
|  8 | h.pdf |   1 |       0 |    4 |
|  9 | i.pdf |   2 |       1 |    4 |
| 10 | j.pdf |   3 |       0 |    4 |
+----+-------+-----+---------+------+
```

In this case I would want to get:

```
+------+-------+-----+---------+
| user | file  | log | billing |
+------+-------+-----+---------+
|    1 | b.pdf |   3 |       1 |
|    2 | d.pdf |   2 |       1 |
|    3 | f.pdf |   3 |       0 |
|    4 | i.pdf |   2 |       1 |
+------+-------+-----+---------+
```

My simplified query so far returns all files for the users but I'm having trouble grouping based on the above parameters.

```
SELECT
    user,
    file,
    log,                        
    billing
FROM 
    files
WHERE
    user IN (
            SELECT
                DISTINCT(user)
            FROM
                tests
            WHERE
                log = 2                     
        )
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN log = 2 AND billing = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN billing = 1 THEN 2
        ELSE -1 
    END
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't be done as single SQL.  Need a view to flatten out data, creating a column for MAX(billing=1) and MAX(billing=0) and then another SQL statement based on the view that selects one or the other.  Also don't know what you're using the Test table for, everything you need is in the File table.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I'm using the test table because that's what contains the definitive users on that particular log. The file table does not handle this since they are handled outside the scope of the log. In the case of user #3, there is no file associated with log #2, so it is handled based on the criteria above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a separate query to get the results based on each of the 3 criteria specified in the OP, then `UNION` the results from these queries and fetch result from first query if available, otherwise from second query, otherwise from third query:

```
SELECT user, file, log, billing
FROM (
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @user=user THEN @row_number+1 
                         ELSE 1 
                    END AS row_number,
       @user:=user AS user,
       file, log, billing
FROM (        
  -- 1st query: has biggest priority 
  SELECT 1 AS pri, t.user, f.file, f.log, f.billing
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user, log
        FROM tests 
        WHERE log = 2) AS t
  INNER JOIN files AS f 
  ON (t.user = f.user AND t.log = f.log AND f.billing = 1)   

  UNION ALL

  -- 2nd query: priority = 2
  SELECT 2 AS pri, t.user, f.file, f.log, f.billing
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user, log
        FROM tests 
        WHERE log = 2) AS t
  INNER JOIN files AS f 
  ON (t.user = f.user AND f.billing = 1)   
  WHERE f.log > t.log OR f.log = 0

  UNION ALL

  -- 3rd query: priority = 3
  SELECT 3 AS pri, t.user, f.file, f.log, f.billing       
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user, log
        FROM tests 
        WHERE log = 2) AS t
  INNER JOIN files AS f ON (t.user = f.user)  
  ORDER BY user, pri, log DESC ) s ) r
WHERE r.row_number = 1
ORDER BY user
```

`pri` column is used so as to discern and prioritize results between the three separate queries. `@row_number` and `@user` variables are used in order to simulate `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY pri)` window function. Using `@row_number` in the outermost query we can select the required record, i.e. the record having the highest priority within each 'user' partition.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffcba/22)

Comment: That's awesome, Giorgos! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @giorgos quick question - is there anything that would inhibit the incrementing of the user vars in a particular version of MySQL? I have created a fiddle with the exact data that I'm pulling from my database - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a231/2 and can recreate your work and results, but as soon as I implement it in my production environment, it does not increment the row_number and ends up with the full list of files (plus a duplicate since one matches two of the cases). Production server has MySQL 5.6.23 but I haven't seen anything in the changelogs that would indicate a difference

Comment: @JBarnes Unfortunately, I only have limited experience working in MySQL production environments. I posted the answer testing it in solely on SQL Fiddle. You can try posting a different question regarding this discrepancy between SQL Fiddle and your production server.

Comment: no problem at all. Thank you so much for the help so far!